# How to call an API from flutter

Tags: rest, flutter

Every time i call  the end point I get an error message. Values Represented are Static for this example but later on these will be replaced by real values, the Goal is to retrieve the values on the database through the Api. the Values, order and entries have be checked for spelling errors. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
class Search {
  final int id;
  final String location;
  final int employer;
  final String service;
  final int position;
  final String userId;

  Search({this.id, this.location, this.employer, this.service, this.position, this.userId});

  factory Search.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Search(
      id: json['id'],
      employer: json['employer'],
      location: json['location'],
      service: json['service'],
      position: json['position'],
    );
  }
  Map<String, String> headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'authorization': 'ztNMKpkGM4USORPl45HGEl8EMyh1'
 };
  Map toMap() {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["employer"] = employer;
    map["location"] = location;
    map["service"] = service;
    map["postion"] = position;

    return map;
  }
}

Future<Search> createSearch(
  int employer, String location, String service, int position) async {
  final http.Response response = await http.post(
      'http://m-waks/employer/asefsdgcsjdsxxx/search-employees/',
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'ztNMKpkGM4USORPl45HGEl8EMyh1','Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
        'employer': employer,
        'location': location,
        'service': service,
        'position': position
      }));

  if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
    throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
  } else {
    return Search.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)['results']);
  }
}
```

the execution for this call is

```
onPressed: () async {
            setState(() {
              _search = createSearch(3,"All Areas","Beautician",0);
            });
}
```

the error Message is here:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter (16592): <html>
E/flutter (16592): ^
E/flutter (16592): 
E/flutter (16592): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1394:5)
E/flutter (16592): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1261:9)
E/flutter (16592): #2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:926:22)
E/flutter (16592): #3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:31:10)
E/flutter (16592): #4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:495:36)
E/flutter (16592): #5      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:153:41)
E/flutter (16592): #6      createSearch (package:m_waks/pages/home_page.dart:68:33)
E/flutter (16592): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16592): #7      _HomePageState._buildList.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:m_waks/pages/home_page.dart:608:25)
E/flutter (16592): #8      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1148:30)
E/flutter (16592): #9      _HomePageState._buildList.<anonymous closure> (package:m_waks/pages/home_page.dart:607:13)
E/flutter (16592): #10     _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
E/flutter (16592): #11     _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36)
E/flutter (16592): #12     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter (16592): #13     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11)
E/flutter (16592): #14     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5)
E/flutter (16592): #15     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:236:7)
E/flutter (16592): #16     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
E/flutter (16592): #17     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:222:20)
E/flutter (16592): #18     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter (16592): #19     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (16592): #20     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter (16592): #21     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (16592): #22     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)
E/flutter (16592): #23     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter (16592): #24     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter (16592): #25     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:273:10)
E/flutter (16592): #26     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:5)
```

Comment: Make sure that you can exercise the API using Postman or equivalent. Currently the API is returning you HTML - presumably an error message. Print the response as it may contains some clues as to the error.

Comment: I have retrieved the response as a String and it is<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
 </body>
 </html>

Comment: If I switch to https it throws a handshake error

Comment: I guess the problem is that you need `await` before calling `createSearch` on the `onPressed`

Comment: So, sounds like the question should really about why you get the handshake error, as your server appears to require HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for the help.... turns out all i needed were http overrides